# TableView and Footer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with around 40 items. The items are for example 1A, 1B, 1C and so on. I want to add a footer for all the row with the 2, and also a footer for 2,3 and 4. I have all the items on a `NSDictionary`. How can i do that?

Comment: Code please. Impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/170/screenshot20120906at191.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your `UITableViewController` to be a `UITableViewDelegate` and a `UITableViewDataSource`.

You should read the documentation for those, and study some of the many tutorials on this topic. Here's one I found quickly:

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/